# paper-dropdown-menu default selected option doesn't work

Tags: polymer, material-design

My Expectation here would be that 'Option 1' would be selected by default once the page loads. This is not what is happening. Instead it shows the label, not the selected option based on the paper-item value attribute.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu name="dropdown" label="Dropdown" selected='1' valueattr='value'>
    <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
        <core-menu class="menu">
            <paper-item value="1">Option 1</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="2">Option 2</paper-item>
        </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `selected` attribute can be used in conjunction with an element that extends `<core-selector>` to control what's selected. Out of the set of elements you're using in your example, [`<core-menu>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-menu) is the one that extends `<core-selector>`, so you need to set the `selected` attribute on that.

Here's a modified example that works as expected:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    
    <h1>Dropdown Menu</h1>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Select an item">
      <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
        <core-menu class="menu" selected="1" valueattr="value">
          <paper-item value="1">Option 1</paper-item>
          <paper-item value="2">Option 2</paper-item>
        </core-menu>
      </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that you need to also set [`valueattr="value"`](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-docs/index.html#core-selector.attributes.valueattr) on the `<core-menu>` to indicate that each of the `<core-menu>` children have `value` attributes set that correspond to what will be passed in to the `select` attribute. (The default is `valueattr="name"` which would require that you set `name` attributes on each of the `<paper-item>`s.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the update for Polymer 1.0 `paper-dropdown-menu`

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Select an item" placeholder="Donut" >
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selected="2" attr-for-selected="data-value">
    <paper-item data-value="1">Croissant</paper-item>
    <paper-item data-value="2">Donut</paper-item>
    <paper-item data-value="3">Financier</paper-item>
    <paper-item data-value="4">Madeleine</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: so you have to explicitly set the placeholder?  Polymer is killing me.

Comment: Have you tried the binding feature? Eg. `placeholder="{{myVar}}"` see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html

Comment: @DavidDouglas is it possible to de-select the selected item of a paper-dropdown? Assigning the myVar to null didn't work for me.

Comment: This is no longer true for v1.1.2 I tried the sample code from the docs and its no longer working. :(

Comment: @lionheart have you figured de-selecting out?

Comment: Also, if you set placeholder, it is greyed out.